# What is the best way to add a new user and group during install of new sw?

Tags: linux, bash, debian, python

I need to create a set-up procedure that add a new user and group on the system which will be used to run the application;
like when you install a program like mariaDb or openSSh.
What is the best way to do that?
Now i use a bash script with python subprocess module; but this give me a lots of dubt.
And later...how i can run a program as another user?
Thank.

Comment: Are you making your own .deb packages, or are you using a script to do everything?

Comment: hi. I'm, trying, to do a script that take care of doing whatever is needed. I looked for mariadb source on github to find something similar, but i didn't find nothing.

Comment: That's because mariadb users generally just use packages – they don't try to reinvent the wheel, they just let the package manager do these tasks.

Comment: That's ok. So: the best way is to package my sw. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To create a new user or group on a debian system you use the commands `adduser`, `addgroup` (which are wrappers to `useradd` and `groupadd`):

```sh
$ man 8 adduser
```

The package installation routines use the same command.

If you want to create a *system* user or group, versus a "normal" user (with login shell), you use the invocation

```
$ adduser --system [...]
```

as in

```
$ adduser --system --home /var/local/lib/mysrv --group --disabled-login mysrv
Adding system user `mysrv' (UID 137) ...
Adding new group `mysrv' (GID 173) ...
Adding new user `mysrv' (UID 137) with group `mysrv' ...
Creating home directory `/var/local/lib/mysrv' ...
```

This will create the system user `mysrv` and group `mysrv`, add it to that group, and create a homedir for it in `/var/local/lib/mysrv` (where it can drop it's data and logfiles or such).

To remove it again, use `deluser --remove-home mysrv`.
For more options, read the manpage.

---

How to *run* your program as this new user will depend on your preferences and code.
Basically you need to be root first, then switch to the user (as a system service doesn't "log in").

This can be done for example by using `cron` and installing a system-wide cronjob (where you can specify the user to run it as).

Another method (and probably the best one) is using a supervisor, such as [daemontools](https://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html) or [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/).

The last option is to become a system daemon, with all that entails.
If your program is written as a daemon, the init system will handle it (systemd, sysvinit, ...), but you'll need to write init scripts for it.

Running a secure system service is non-trivial, but there are tools that help you with this, such as `daemon` and `python-daemon` (both debian packages).

> daemon(1) turns other processes into daemons. There are many tasks that need to be performed to correctly set up a daemon process. This can be tedious. daemon performs these tasks for other processes.

Read the manpage.